# How to control swipe to dismiss for individual list item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I am using two `ItemTouchHelper` objects, one for *LEFT* swiping and corresponding operations and another for *RIGHT* swiping and corresponding operations. In my list, few items must have only left swiping enabled and few must have only right swiping enabled.

But the problem is if I attach my `RecyclerView` to both the Helper objects, then each object is swipe-able on both the direction.

Is there any method to control individual list items for Swipe to Dismiss in *ItemTouchListener*?

> P.S. not interested in external libraries

Comment: Show your code here for better help

Comment: `itemTouchhelper1.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)`
`itemTouchHelper2.attachToRecyclerView(recycerView)`
where object 1 is for left swipe and object 2 for right swipe. This is what I have done till now @Vickyexpert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ItemTouchHelper.Callback.getMovementFlags(...)` (or alternatively `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback.getSwipeDirs(...)`). It gets the `ViewHolder` as parameter.

Set a flag on the `ViewHolder` in `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder(...)` if the represented item can be swiped left or right or none. Query that flag in the above mentioned method(s) and return an according value.